# Overhead of implicit object wrappers in Scala

Tags: scala, wrapper, implicit

Consider the following, very simple code :

```
class A(val a: String, val b: Int)
object Test {
  implicit class wrap(obj: A) {
    def fn = obj.a + obj.b
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) =
    println(new A("Hello", 1).fn)
}
```

Disassembling the code yields :

```
public void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #29; //Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
   3:   aload_0
   4:   new #31; //class A
   7:   dup
   8:   ldc #33; //String Hello
   10:  iconst_1
   11:  invokespecial   #36; //Method A."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
   14:  invokevirtual   #38; //Method wrap:(LA;)LTest$wrap;
   17:  invokevirtual   #42; //Method Test$wrap.fn:()Ljava/lang/String;
   20:  invokevirtual   #46; //Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   23:  return
```

The compiler effectively creates the wrapper object when using `fn` implicitly.

While I'm well aware that JIT compilation could eliminate this, that premature optimization is bad, and that I'm unlikely to run into any performance problems in most of my code, creating a static function under-the-hood doesn't seem like a lot of work for the compiler, and would eliminate this.

So, here you go, I'm simply curious : **is there any particular reason the Scala team decided not to include this optimization?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case there is no way to tell whether you want to use A as a normal class or whether you intend to use it as an implicit wrapper. For classes that are simply wrapping a type you can exploit value classes which should desugar into the behavior you want(aka no wrapper class), just method invocation with the first argument being the wrapped value. Unfortunately they only work for classes with constructors of arity one.

```
 object Test {
   implicit class A(val a: String) extends AnyVal {
     def foo: String = a 
   }

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     "Hello World!".foo
   }
 }
```

This has the side effect of that code like this usually compiles into a module load, followed by invokevirtual. This could be optimized, and work is being done by Miguel Garcia on getting these kind of situations to be a ["really static"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/scala-internals/@reallyStatic/scala-internals/7t-cAqNN0BA/eGfx13hJnzEJ).